# Is it possible to display post title in reverse word order?

Tags: custom-post-types

I created alphabetical list of members(custom post) using first letter of title. Therefore title was in format 'Surname - Name'. Now on single member page I need somehow to reverse order to 'Name - Surname'. Is it possible?

```
<?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
```

Comment: Do you need the `-` also in between? And will there be just 2 words? If there are 3 or more words, how would you like to display?

Answer (score 2):

There will be a lot of ways to solve this. One of them is to modify template of single CPT post and replace:

```
<?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
```

with:

```
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php
    $separator = ' - ';
    echo implode( $separator, array_reverse( explode( $separator, get_the_title() ) ) );
?></h1>
```

What it will do is:

1. Take the title.
2. Explode it into pieces using ' - ' as separator.
3. Reverse the pieces.
4. Glue them together using ' - ' as separator again.
5. Echo the result.

Comment: Thanks for response! Actually there is no dash between. $separator ='  '; solved the problem! Great!

Comment: That's why I made that separator easy to customize ;)

Comment: @VedranSadić remember to mark answer as correct to keep the site clean and tidy.